# How to fix: "ABI filter 'arm64-v8a' is no longer supported in NDK version x"

Tags: android-ndk

I'm setting up an android project from another company which involves selfmade C++ cross platform libraries. For an older version of these libraries an complete app project was made in java with a jni interface to access these libraries, which are stored as their own modules with gradle.build files. The goal is to get the app compiling for arm64-v8a architecture because of the Google requirements for app update.

The project is set up with:

- gradle experimental plugin 0.11.0
- gradle plugin 4.1
- boost 1.64.0 for armeabi-v7a (got arm64-v8a precompiled libraries as replacement)
- opencv 2.4.13.2
- ndk r15c

I checked all dependencies for getting a arm64 pendant, which was only needed for the boost dependencies.

I tried changing the ABI list which is used for every project to include all architectures or all seperatly. I tried using other ndk versions. What might help but i didn't accomplish was changing the experimental gradle plugin to the normal plugin but i couldn't get that right.

I expected some compiling or linking errors but it only tells me "ABI filter 'arm64-v8a' is no longer supported in NDK version r15.2.4203891.". If i try other architectures i get the same error, but instead of the 'arm64-v8a' the current selected architecture. If i give an invalid architecture it changes to "Target ABI 'hello' is not supported.", so it recognizes the architecture i think.

Stacktrace of first error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#configureNativeLibrary(ModelMap, NdkConfig, NdkHandler, ModelMap, File, ServiceRegistry) > create(livestage) > withType()
>   Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#configureNativeLibrary(ModelMap, NdkConfig, NdkHandler, ModelMap, File, ServiceRegistry) > create(lib-jni-cxx) > withType()
>   Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#configureNativeBinary(BinaryContainer, ModelMap, NdkConfig, NdkHandler) > withType()
>   ABI filter 'arm64-v8a' is no longer supported in NDK version r15.2.4203891.

Comment: You should upgrade to NDK r20.

Answer (score 0):

The experimental plugin hasn't been supported for years, so it's no surprise that it doesn't work. Migrate to `externalNativeBuild`: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code